# Should it be written in the topics page that questions asking about a broad overview of a game world are offtopic?

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

I don't really have a good name for it, but Questions that ask, broadly, what is the lore behind a game, like this one. [What is the backstory of the Witcher's world creation?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/315034/what-is-the-backstory-of-the-witchers-world-creation)

I think we should write it in the rules here : https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic

Questions asking about a broad overview of the world of a game should not be on topic.

There's a line to make here between asking about something precise in the lore of a game, and making a question that is basically asking to get a TLDR of the world of a game.

Comment: I agree. Specific to this case, I love the Witcher lore, and I'd love to learn about it. But its story is so massive, as any game's lore/backstory might be, that it may not be the best fit for it here...

Comment: @Kaizerwolf In that case, wouldn't that simply warrant a Too Broad close vote?

Comment: @DanmakuGrazer I would agree, but I think what cazc says still applies. if we try to accept "tell me everything ever about this game's lore", it would make for a quiet a mess. But, in a specific case, let's say something pertaining to Geralt's hatred of portals, I think that's more than fair. Those are smaller, more bite-size pieces of lore that we can handle.

Comment: Asking about certain parts of lore is perfectly fine as long as it is reasonably bounded, if it's not, we can just cast a close vote for too broad and try and get the asker to narrow the scope of their question. I don't think we need explicit wording in the topics page about this.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf actually, I can't remember why Geralt hates portals, and I'm on the 5th book of the series...

Comment: @Fredy31 I believe he was referencing [this question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/311109/145980) from around a month ago.

Comment: In regards to the question asked specifically, narrowing down the scope of it would help a lot. That's why I left the comment on it that I did. Asking about an entire world is a bit much, but there's a lot that you can narrow down when asking about an entire backstory about a world.

Comment: @Kaizerwolf Wait, what did I say?  I don't remember commenting on this matter, although it's possible

Comment: @cazc_941 well I can't seem to find it either, but I know I was referencing something you had said!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Actually, it's already in the [help center](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/help/closed-questions):

> if your question could be answered by an entire book, or has many valid answers (but no way to determine which - if any - are correct), then it is probably **too broad** for our format.

Lore questions on their own are not off-topic. There's nothing wrong with asking why certain events lead up to some given climax. However, asking the community to recount all of those events is a little too much. Additionally, the post is actually asking a couple questions in one.

Also, remember that a question that is *on hold* is not the same as a *closed* or *deleted* question. If a question is on hold, that means we're encouraging the asker to fix what is wrong with it. If they put some effort in and make it a good question, it will be reopened. If they don't, the question still isn't deleted - it only gets "closed". We only really delete questions if they are irretrievably off topic.

If this question narrowed down its scope, it could be opened again.